# How can I make pandas apply faster if I only use pandas built-in function in it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example I have a dataframe `df` :

| trade_date | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-04 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 7 | 11 | 12 |
| 2010-01-05 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 7 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-06 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 7 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-07 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 7 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-08 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-11 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-12 00:00:00 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-13 00:00:00 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-14 00:00:00 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 12 | 11 |
| 2010-01-15 00:00:00 | 6 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 12 | 11 |

and I want to get this result:

```
df.apply(lambda r: r.nlargest(2).index.max(), axis=1)
```

All functions used in apply are numpy/pandas's built-in function, so I think there should be some way to get rid of python level for loop and make this transform much faster.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For improve performance use numpy - get position of sorted values by [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) with filter first top 2 values with indexing and converting value to negative, then get columns names with maximal:

```
print (df)
                      01  02  03  04   05  06  07  08   09  10  11  12
trade_date                                                            
2010-01-04 00:00:00    5  40  20   1    3   6   8   9   10   7  11  12
2010-01-05 00:00:00    5   4   3   1    2   6   8   9   10   7  12  11
2010-01-06 00:00:00    5   4   3   1    2   6   8   9  100   7  12  11
2010-01-07 00:00:00    5   4   3   1    2   6   8   9   10   7  12  11
2010-01-08 00:00:00    5   4   3   1   20   6   7   9   10   8  12  11
2010-01-11 00:00:00    5  40   3  10   20   6   7   9   10   8  12  11
2010-01-12 00:00:00    5   4   3   1    2   6   7   9   10   8  12  11
2010-01-13 00:00:00    6   4   3   1    2   5   7   9   10   8  12  11
2010-01-14 00:00:00  600  40   3   1    2   5   7   9   10   8  12  11
2010-01-15 00:00:00    6   5   3   1  200   4  70   9   10   8  12  11

print (df.apply(lambda r: r.nlargest(2).index.max(), axis=1))
trade_date
2010-01-04 00:00:00    03
2010-01-05 00:00:00    12
2010-01-06 00:00:00    11
2010-01-07 00:00:00    12
2010-01-08 00:00:00    11
2010-01-11 00:00:00    05
2010-01-12 00:00:00    12
2010-01-13 00:00:00    12
2010-01-14 00:00:00    02
2010-01-15 00:00:00    07
dtype: object

c = df.columns.to_numpy()
print (np.max(c[np.argsort(-df.to_numpy())[:, :2]], axis=1))
['03' '12' '11' '12' '11' '05' '12' '12' '02' '07']
```